# Como posso capturar um favicon de um site via PHP?

Tags: php, php-domdocument, php-domxpath

Carrego um conteúdo externo de um site e depois importo ele para o `DOMDocument`.

Atualmente, consigo capturar a informação da tag `title` facilmente.

Faço assim:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHtml('<?xml encoding="UTF-8" ?>' . $conteudo_html)

$title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Porém, gostaria de, através do próprio `DomDocument`,capturar também `favicon` desse conteúdo.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

**Nota**: Se haver uma maneira  de fazer isso com o `DOMXPath`, vai ser melhor ainda.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se pode fazer isso, mas tente `$fav = $dom->querySelector('link[rel*="shortcut icon"]');`

Comment: No caso eu retornaria ali a tag <link>

Comment: Outro problema: url relativa!

Answer (score 3):

Por um jeito meio braçal consegui visualizar pelo atributo `rel="shortcut icon"`, ou seja, pego todos que são `tag` *link* (`$dom->getElementsByTagName('link');`) e depois verifico seu atributo *rel* (`$itens->item($i)->getAttribute('rel') === 'shortcut icon'`), e jogo isso em um array. Só tem que fazer uma adaptação naquele site aonde o mesmo possui vários, seguindo a mesma lógica!

```
<?php

    //endereço do site  
    $site = ''

    $conteudo_html = file_get_contents($site);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    @$dom->loadHtml('<?xml encoding="UTF-8" ?>' . $conteudo_html);

    $itens = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
    $count = $itens->length;


    $finds = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {

        if ($itens->item($i)->getAttribute('rel') === 'shortcut icon')
        {

            array_push($finds, [
                'tag' => 'link', 
                'href' => $itens->item($i)->getAttribute('href'),
                'id' => 'shortcut icon',                
                'type' => $itens->item($i)->getAttribute('type'),
                ]
            );

        }

    }

    //itens encontrados
    var_dump($finds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai um exemplo bem simples, disponível na página do `PHP.net` porém, com algumas modificações, para lidar com erros, e portabilidade, por ser uma função.

```
function getUrl($url){
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    // Aqui suprimi os erros, prepositadamente;
    if(!@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url)){
        $err="";    
        $erros = libxml_get_errors();
        foreach($erros as $erro){
            $err .= $erro->message;    
        }    
        return $err;
    } else {
        $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
        $arr = $xml->xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
        return $arr[0]['href'];    
    }
    
}

// Ativar a gestão de erros
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

echo getUrl("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
```

---

## Referências:

[XML - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php)

[Favicon Class - Controlstyle](http://www.controlstyle.com/articles/programming/text/php-favicon/)

[How to get favicon from websites using PHP - SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701593/how-to-get-a-websites-favicon-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando o Stackoverflow como exemplo:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/favicon.ico?v=c6678b633455">


$html = file_get_contents('http://pt.stackoverflow.com');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$favicon = $xpath->evaluate("//link[@rel='shortcut icon']");

print_r($favicon->item(0)->getAttribute('href'));
```

Retornará:

> //cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/favicon.ico?v=c6678b633455

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro a utilização da Biblioteca Simple Dom: [Simple Html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Exemplo:

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('http://pt.stackoverflow.com/');

echo $html->find('link[rel="shortcut icon"]', 0)->href;
```

**Sáida:** //cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/favicon.ico?v=c6678b633455

Answer (score 0):

Uma ideia que posso te dar é, primeiro capture a url do site usando `curl()` ou `file_get_contents()`:

```
  <?php

if (isset($_GET['img'])) {
    $favicon = $_GET['img'];
    print_r(array('favicon'=>$favicon));
  die(); 
}

function capturarFaviconSite($url_metodo) {

$script = "\n" . '<script>' .
                 'function captureFavicon() {
                     var objSerializer = new XMLSerializer(), favicon;
                     var expFormat = /href="(.+).[png|ico|jpg|(.+)?v=(.+)]"/gi;
                     var expCheck = /(rel="icon"|rel="shortcut icon"|type="image\/png"|rel="apple-touch-icon")/gi;
                     var all = document.querySelectorAll("link");
                     for (var i in all) {
                           var fav = objSerializer.serializeToString(all[i]); 
                     if (expCheck.test(fav)) {
                         favicon = expFormat.exec(fav)[0]
                         .replace("href=\"","")
                         .replace("\"","");
                         break;
                      }
                   }
                   if (favicon!="") {
                       location.href="?img="+escape(favicon);
                   }
                 }';

$html = file_get_contents($url_metodo);
        return preg_replace('/<\/head>/',$script . 'captureFavicon();'."\n".'</script></head>',$html);
}

echo capturarFaviconSite('http://www.uol.com.br');
```

No caso acima, o que estou fazendo é retornando isso por um método javascript:

```
function captureFavicon() {

  var objSerializer = new XMLSerializer(), favicon;
  var expFormat = /href="(.+).[png|ico|jpg|(.+)?v=(.+)]"/gi;
  var expCheck = /(rel="icon"|rel="shortcut icon"|type="image\/png"|rel="apple-touch-icon")/gi;
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('link');
  for (var i in all) {
       var fav = objSerializer.serializeToString(all[i]); 
       if (expCheck.test(fav)) {
           favicon = expFormat.exec(fav)[0]
          .replace("href=\"",'')
          .replace("\"",'');
       break;
      }
  }
return favicon;
}
```

Comment: Como vou carregar isso via javascript? Geralmente requisições ajax são bloqueadas. Por isso é que eu fiz um proxying via php

Comment: pode usar `curl` ou `simplexml_load_file`

Comment: E colocar o javascript em baixo.